# Retrieve and use service 'Log on as' credentials in C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, wmi

I'm currently writing a Windows Service which will be required to interact with an on-premise Exchange server. Quite rightly, we've come to the conclusion that hard-coding the Exchange credentials is a very bad idea, but so is storing them in a config file in plain text. We've come to the conclusion that creating a service account that owns the mailbox in question should satisfy our requirements, however I've hit the following problem:

I've started to use a ManagementObjectSearcher to get the Username of the account running a service on my PC, however I'm not sure how to, or even if, I can get the password. I've tried this:

```
    class Program
{

    public static ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_Service where name = 'netlogon'"));

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ManagementObjectCollection Response = Searcher.Get();

        Console.WriteLine(Response.Count);

        foreach (ManagementObject Item in Response)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Item.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, I don't get a Password back. There's some suggestion from the EWS API documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn626019(v=exchg.150).aspx) that I can grab the credentials of the currently logged in user, but I looked through the referenced code samples and can find no suggestion of how this is doable.

For clarity, I can get the username, that's fine. I need the password... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: could you have the exchange account use windows credentials, and run your application using the same windows account, therefore you wouldn't need to search for or store those credentials? Even if it's on a separate domain (or using 2 local accounts, 1 for applications and another for exchange), so long as the windows credentials have the same username and password, it should still work.

Comment: What are you going to do with the password? I doubt AD will hand it over to you easily....

Comment: @rene - I've to provide credentials to Exchange using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data - I'm not fussy about how I do it, but the credentials that the service runs under should be the same credentials I pass into ExchangeService.Credentials.

Comment: I would expect that you could get the credetials from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: @Rene,Thanks - a perfectly acceptable and useful answer. However I also found out that I can simply 'pass-through' the credentials needed to the EWS API by not specifying any credentials!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are two acceptable answers:

One that @rene proposed involves using the Microsoft CredentialCache type to return the network credentials of the currently logged in user, which in a service context seems to just be the 'log on as' credentials. Details found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx

The second is one that I Found, which involves simply not adding credentials to the EWS API ExchangeService type, in which case the credentials of the users running the service will automatically be passed through to Exchange.